# Button in data template not recognizinng command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Button in a data template with a command in a list view of items not working. I have tried other data templates with stack panel.
The button to search for the initial items will recognize it's command and work.

Here is the page with the data template for the items:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfFstApp1.Pages"
  xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:WpfFstApp1.ViewModels" x:Class="WpfFstApp1.Pages.CsvPage"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="CsvPage">


<Page.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:CsvViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>


<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CsvTemp">
        <ListView>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Dir}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FiPath}"/>
            <Button Content="Click To Open" Command="{Binding OpenFiCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelResult.FiPath}"></Button>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Refs}"/>
        </ListView>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>


<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="55"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="Project" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="16" Width="37"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Sales Line" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="16" Width="52"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Part Number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="16" Width="68"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtBoxProj" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" 
             TextAlignment="Right" MaxLines="1" Text="{Binding SearchVal1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtBoxSline" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="65,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" MaxLines="1" MaxLength="25" 
             TextAlignment="Right" CharacterCasing="Upper" Text="{Binding SearchVal2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtBoxPart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="155,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
             TextAlignment="Right" MaxLines="1" CharacterCasing="Upper" Text="{Binding SearchVal3, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

    <Button x:Name="BtnSrch" Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="280,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Command="{Binding SearchCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>

    <ListView Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding OcResults}" ItemTemplate="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource CsvTemp}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelResult}"/>

    <StatusBar Grid.Row="2" FontSize="14" Margin="1,0,1,1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <TextBlock x:Name="tsTxtBlck1" Text="{Binding CurStat1}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="tsTxtBlck2" Text="{Binding CurStat2}"/>
    </StatusBar>

</Grid>
```

Here is the Model :

```
class SearchResult
{
    public string Dir { get; set; }
    public string FiName { get; set; }
    public string FiPath { get; set; }
    public List<string> Refs { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my ViewModel :

```
class CsvViewModel : ModelBase
{

    #region [ Declarations ]
    //
    bool Init = false;
    string CurDir = string.Empty;
    //Count of files traversed and timer for diagnostic output
    int fileCount = 0;
    Stopwatch sw;
    public List<SearchResult> ResList;
    //
    #endregion


    #region [ Properties ]
    //
    public ObservableCollection<SearchResult> OcResults { get; set; }
    //
    private string _curStat1;
    public string CurStat1
    {
        get { return _curStat1; }
        set { _curStat1 = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurStat1)); }
    }

    private string _curStat2;
    public string CurStat2
    {
        get { return _curStat2; }
        set { _curStat2 = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurStat2)); }
    }
    //
    private string _searchVal1 = string.Empty;
    public string SearchVal1
    {
        get { return _searchVal1; }
        set { _searchVal1 = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SearchVal1)); }
    }

    private string _searchVal2 = string.Empty;
    public string SearchVal2
    {
        get { return _searchVal2; }
        set { _searchVal2 = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SearchVal2)); }
    }

    private string _searchVal3 = string.Empty;
    public string SearchVal3
    {
        get { return _searchVal3; }
        set { _searchVal3 = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SearchVal3)); }
    }
    //
    public RelCom SearchCommand { get; private set; }
    public RelCom OpenFiCommand { get; private set; }
    //
    private SearchResult selResult;
    public SearchResult SelResult
    {
        get { return selResult; }
        set { selResult = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelResult)); }
    }
    //
    #endregion


    public CsvViewModel()
    {
        ResList = new List<SearchResult>();
        OcResults = new ObservableCollection<SearchResult>();
        SearchCommand = new RelCom(Search_CanExecute, Search);
        OpenFiCommand = new RelCom(OpenFi_CanExecute, OpenFile);
    }


    private bool Search_CanExecute(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void Search(object obj)
    {
        CurDir = string.Empty;
        //
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchVal1))
            SearchVal2 = SearchVal1.Trim() + " " + SearchVal2.Trim();
        //
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchVal3))
            SearchVal3 = SearchVal3.Trim();
        //
        try
        {
            TraverseTreeParallelForEach(@"\\ast-sigmanest\Feedback\Feedback", (f) =>
            {
                // Exceptions are no-ops.
                try
                {
                    // Do nothing with the data except read it to find string...
                    FileInfo fi1 = new FileInfo(f);
                    bool addfi = false;
                    //
                    string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(f);
                    List<string> refLines = new List<string>();
                    foreach (string line in Lines)
                    {
                        if (line.Contains(SearchVal2) & line.Contains(SearchVal3))
                        {
                            addfi = true;
                            refLines.Add(line);
                        }
                    }
                    //
                    if (addfi)
                    {
                        SearchResult Sres = new SearchResult { Dir = fi1.Directory.ToString(), FiName = fi1.Name, FiPath = fi1.FullName, Refs = refLines };
                        ResList.Add(Sres);
                    }
                    //
                    //contents = null;
                    Lines = null;
                    fi1 = null;
                    //
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException) { }
                catch (IOException) { }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
                catch (SecurityException) { }
                // Display the filename.
                //Console.WriteLine(f);
            });
        }
        catch (ArgumentException Ae)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Ae.Message);
        }
        //
        var resgrp = (from res in ResList group res by res.Dir into newres orderby newres.Key select newres);
        foreach (var rgrp in resgrp)
        {
            foreach (var res in rgrp)
            {
                OcResults.Add(res);
            }
        }
        //
    }


    private bool OpenFi_CanExecute(object obj)
    {
        return obj != null;
    }

    private void OpenFile(object obj)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(SelResult.FiPath));
    }


    public void TraverseTreeParallelForEach(string root, Action<string> action)
    {
        //Count of files traversed and timer for diagnostic output
        fileCount = 0;
        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        // Determine whether to parallelize file processing on each folder based on processor count.
        int procCount = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;

        // Data structure to hold names of subfolders to be examined for files.
        Stack<string> dirs = new Stack<string>();

        if (!Directory.Exists(root))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        dirs.Push(root);

        while (dirs.Count > 0)
        {
            string currentDir = dirs.Pop();
            string[] subDirs = { };
            string[] files = { };

            try
            {
                subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(currentDir);
                // Push the subdirectories onto the stack for traversal.
                // This could also be done before handing the files.
                foreach (string str in subDirs)
                    dirs.Push(str);
            }
            // Thrown if we do not have discovery permission on the directory.
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                continue;
            }
            // Thrown if another process has deleted the directory after we retrieved its name.
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                continue;
            }
            //
            try
            {
                files = Directory.GetFiles(currentDir, "*.csv");
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                continue;
            }
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                continue;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                continue;
            }
            //
            // Execute in parallel if there are enough files in the directory.
            // Otherwise, execute sequentially.Files are opened and processed
            // synchronously but this could be modified to perform async I/O.
            try
            {
                if (files.Length < procCount)
                {
                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        action(file);
                        fileCount++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(files, () => 0, (file, loopState, localCount) =>
                    {
                        action(file);
                        return (int)++localCount;
                    },
                                     (c) =>
                                     {
                                         Interlocked.Add(ref fileCount, c);
                                     });
                }
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                ae.Handle((ex) =>
                {
                    if (ex is UnauthorizedAccessException)
                    {
                        // Here we just output a message and go on.
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        return true;
                    }
                    // Handle other exceptions here if necessary...

                    return false;
                });
            }
            //
        }
        //
    }
}
```

For some reason the button in the data template does not trigger the command, even though it shows to be bound to it.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the Open command know that the CanExecute conditions have changed, do this in your `SelResult` setter:

```
((RelayCommand<object>)OpenFiCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
```

This is one of the reasons I don't like using `CanExecute`.